# MySQL wrong sort order - Ignoring first column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure where I create a temporary table as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE order_report_temp 
( spid INT(10) UNSIGNED,
sp_title VARCHAR(255),
pmnt_title VARCHAR(255),
pmnt_period VARCHAR(20),
kay_id INT(10) UNSIGNED,
kay_title VARCHAR(255),
kay_description VARCHAR(255),
kad VARCHAR(255),
kay_amount FLOAT,
wo_code VARCHAR(50),
cost_center VARCHAR(255),
sp_place VARCHAR(255),
wo_type INT(2)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

I insert data in that table and in the end I do a:

```
SELECT * FROM order_report_temp ORDER BY spid, kay_id, wo_type;
```

In the data table I get as output I have:

```
spid------kay_id
29248.....1475 (ETC....)
29248.....1475 (ETC....)
29256.....1475 (ETC....)
29248.....1476 (ETC....)
29248.....1476 (ETC....)
29256.....1476 (ETC....)
```

The correct result would be:

```
spid------kay_id
29248.....1475 (ETC....)
29248.....1475 (ETC....)
29248.....1476 (ETC....)
29248.....1476 (ETC....)
29256.....1475 (ETC....)
29256.....1476 (ETC....)
```

It seems to be prioritizing the kay_id column over the spid one even though spid is first in the ORDER BY statement. Or it's ignoring the spid completely.
spid is NOT a VARCHAR so this behavior should not be happening.
Any ideas? Is this a known bug or something?

My mySQL version is 5.0.10

Comment: Either MySQL is drunk (happens a lot), or you're doing something wrong (this one). If it's an `int`, it will sort correctly. Have you tried this on a non-temporary table?

Comment: make it happen here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6971/2 and we can help you :p

Comment: Guys I've been torturing myself for more than an hour and now I feel like a retard. I had declared a variable named spid which i used in the beggining of the procedure and this was the only query I didn't use an alias for the table so mySQL used the variable for sorting I guess.
There can be a lesson taught here: ALWAYS USE ALIASES FOR YOUR TABLES IN STORED PROCEDURE QUERIES.

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos: As documented under [Local Variable Scope and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/local-variable-scope.html), "*A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a `SELECT ... INTO` statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable.*"  I tend to prefix my variables and sproc parameters with an underscore to avoid such confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment above I found my (stupid) mistake. I think more people might stumble uppon the same issue and there IS a lesson to be taught here so I post the solution:

I had declared a variable named spid which i used in the beggining of the procedure and this was the only query I didn't use an alias for the table so mySQL used the variable for sorting instead of the column I wanted I guess.

So I replaced the select query with this one:

```
SELECT tmp.* FROM order_report_temp tmp ORDER BY tmp.spid, tmp.kay_id, tmp.wo_type;
```

note to self: **ALWAYS USE ALIASES FOR YOUR TABLES IN STORED PROCEDURE QUERIES**
or as eggyal pointed out I should use prefixes for my local variables in order to avoid them having the same name as a column.